# Which is the best option to upload large size files to azure blob storage using Go?

Tags: azure, go, memory, memory-management, azure-blob-storage

I have creates an application using Go which will upload mp4 files to azure blob storage.

For now, I'm using `azblob.UploadBufferToBlockBlob` function to upload mp4 files to the blob URL.
In this approach, first I need to convert the video files into an array of bytes and then I could pass the array of bytes to the `azblob.UploadBufferToBlockBlob` function.

I'm using go routines to upload multiple mp4 files concurrently but my fear is what if I need to upload a large size file (say 5GB). The entire 5GB must be stored as an array of bytes. What will happen to the memory in this case?

Does the file size really affects this approach? If yes, is there any alternative function to upload large files using Go?

Comment: [UploadFileToBlockBlob](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob#UploadFileToBlockBlob)

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks. Will look into this function.